# How to draw a time-series chart with two array columns(date, value) on google looker studio?

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I have a data source that have 2 columns, "date" and "value".

It sorted by created time, for example,

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| ["2011-10-11", "2011-10-12", "2011-10-13"] | [1,2,3] |

Is there any way to create a chart for x-axis with `date`, y-axis with `value`?

Read looker studio docs, and try custom column but there's no processing method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Custom SQL` in Looker Studio, you can flatten the array and visualize it.

```sql
select
  date, value 
from unnest(["2011-10-11", "2011-10-12", "2011-10-13"]) date with offset idx1
join unnest([1, 2, 3]) value with offset idx2 
on idx1 = idx2;
```

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2011-10-11 | 1 |
| 2011-10-12 | 2 |
| 2011-10-13 | 3 |

[image: Looker Studio - Chart]

Comment: You saved my life friend